# Unable to access tty in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tty

I'm unable to access tty in my Ubuntu 18.04 system. After I installed the Nvidia proprietary drivers and rebooted my system, My screen just turned black. I have searched for shortcuts to enter tty to purge the Nvidia drivers. But I'm unable to enter tty with the key combinations ranging from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>
Could someone kindly help me with my issue?

Comment: check how to configure the start with "--nomodeset" with in grub. Which nvidia card do you have? [or use the single user mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638483/grub-shell-boot-without-graphics-drivers)

Comment: If the computer is connected to the network, you can still access it via ssh (assumed it is already installed and enabled).

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot log in, nor are in the possibility to switch to a TTY to log in (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (or F4 through F7), you still have the option [to boot to a recovery prompt](https://linuxhint.com/boot-ubuntu-into-recovery-mode/).

From a text console, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> returns to the login screen, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to the desktop (if running).

Comment: I have tried the way, but it still could not swith to a TTY, the screen is still black

Comment: You still have the option to boot to a recovery prompt